# chartjs change data animation

Tags: javascript, chart.js

**Is there any way in chartjs to make the same place change animation as [in this video](https://youtu.be/iSifQY9DEtQ), or in some other way not included in chartjs.
I attach the existing code below**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: [],
      borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
      borderWidth: 0.1,
      data: []
    }],
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: '',
    },
    showAllTooltips: true,
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      displayColors: false,
      xAlign: `left`,
      yAlign: `center`,
      bodyFontSize: 16,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(240, 240, 240, 0)',
      bodyFontColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(240, 240, 240, 1)',
      callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
          return `${tooltipItem.xLabel}`;
        },
        title: function (tooltipItem, data) {
          return;
        }
      }
    },
    legend: { display: false },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 500,
          display: true
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawBorder: false,
        }
      }],
    }
  }
});

let number = 0;
window.onload = function () {


  function load() {
    let users = [];
    let data = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      users.push(db[number].users[i].username);
      data.push(db[number].users[i].data);
    }

    myChart.options.title.text = `Leaderboard on ${db[number].date}`
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data = data;
    myChart.data.labels = users;
    myChart.update({
      duration: 800,
      easing: 'easeOutBounce'
    });
    number++;
  }
  setInterval(function () {
    load();
  }, 600);
  load();
}
```

**If you need more details in the future, I can attach the entire code, if it helps of course. I've been trying to come up with something for a few days, but nothing works out, I hope for help.**